# Should I connect to the blockchain from the client or server side?

Tags: web3js, nodejs, jquery

I am trying to build a simple Dapp for buying and trading tokens.

Which of the following would be a better way to integrate with blockchain:

1. On the server side
2. On the client side

Which is more efficient? I don't think security will be a concern as blockchain data is already hashed.

Comment: What are you trying to build? I think both are valid options depending on the scenario.

Comment: CORS might be an issue on client side web3

Comment: A simple Dapp for buying and trading of tokens
Which option will be better?